# OpenPop.Net Exception

Tags: asp.net, .net, openpop

I am using OpenPop.net in my application. What this application does is that it downloads mails from a pop3 account saves all the attachments (CSV files) and processes them. This processing takes a lot of time. I am getting this exception which I am not able to figure out:

```
Exception message: OpenPop.Pop3.Exceptions.PopServerException: The stream used to retrieve responses from was closed
   at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.IsOkResponse(String response)
   at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.SendCommand(String command)
   at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.DeleteMessage(Int32 messageNumber)
```

At the end of processing the CSV, the mails are deleted from the pop3 account. I believe this is where this exception is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really having two issues here.
One is that you are doing a lot of processing while being connected to the POP3 server. When you are idle too long, the server will simply disconnect you to save resources.
What you should do, is fetch one email, process the attachments and then reconnect to fetch the next. You could also fetch all the attachments and then process them offline.

Second, I guess you are connecting to a gmail account. Gmail has some weird characteristics. [A thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530781/what-non-standard-behaviour-features-does-gmail-exhibit-when-it-is-programmatica) tries to find these characteristics. One of them is that, when you have fetched an email, it will not be available in the next POP3 session with the server. You can connect using a [special username](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47948), where you append `recent:` in front of your normal username. This will show you the emails received in the last 30 days, despite of having been showed to an earlier POP3 session.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something is trying to read a stream that has already been closed.  Are you handling the streams at all, or is this done completely internal to the API?  If you are handling them at all, there is a chance you are closing the streams (this often happens if someone uses a `StreamReader`, most people don't realize that closing the `StreamReader` also closes the underlying stream).

Comment: I am not handling any stream. Though i see some option for stream in the Connect method that i am using.

Comment: What are you passing in for that stream?

Comment: i am using this constructor public void Connect(
   string hostname,
   int port,
   bool useSsl
); There is another one like this public void Connect(
   Stream inputStream,
   Stream outputStream
);

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like either the server is closing the stream on you or something is going on internal to the API.  I would probably suspect the API first.  If you don't already, grab a copy of Reflector (it's free), and look at the code in the DLL and see if you can determine why it's failing.  Or search online for the people who have had a similar problem with the API.