# OpenPop - Gmail - GetMessageCount() returns 0 (zero)

Tags: c#, asp.net, openpop

When connecting to Gmail with OpenPop, I can only retrieve an email once, even if I do not delete it. Using GetMessageCount() I always receive 0 emails. How can I get all the emails that are there?

Only after reading them and processing them do I give order to delete. I am using the following code to get the emails:

```
using (var client = new Pop3Client())
{
    // Connect to the server
    client.Connect(serverData.Hostname, serverData.Port, serverData.UseSsl);

    // Authenticate ourselves towards the server
    client.Authenticate(serverData.Username, serverData.Password, AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

    var emailAmount = client.GetMessageSizes().Count;

    // Fetch all the current uids seen
    var msgCount = client.GetMessageCount();

   .....
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Gmail is special**. Take a look at [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4531389/477854) which explains the non-standard behavior.

What you are interested in, is that Gmail will **only show a message in *ONE* POP3 session**, unless you do special stuff, like prepending *recent:* in front of your username.

Comment: Is it possible to make my application to have some new session every request? if yes, how? I don't know the technical part of Gmail on how they track the session or apps IDs to know if they answer or not, but it would be cool to "fake" a new ID all the time.

Comment: A "Session" here is just a connection. A new connection implies a new session. That is the only way to get a new session. The problem with gmail is that they only show new emails in ONE session. All later sessions will not see it, unless you do as in the post. For example connecting using your username: "recent:<username>". See the post for details.

Answer (score 1):

Getting only the unread mails is how POP3 is supposed to work. If you want to see and manage older mails, you should use IMAP instead.