# How to read latest email using pop3 c#

Tags: c#, pop3, email-client, openpop

I want to read emial from my gmail account.
I am using "OpenPop.Pop3" to read email from my gmail account, I am using below code :-

```
using OpenPop.Pop3;    
public DataTable ReadEmailsFromId()
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
                {
                    int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
                    for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
                    {
                        table.Rows.Add(client.GetMessage(i).Headers.Subject, client.GetMessage(i).Headers.DateSent);
                        string msdId = client.GetMessage(i).Headers.MessageId;
                        OpenPop.Mime.Message msg = client.GetMessage(i);
                        OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart plainTextPart = msg.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
                        string message = plainTextPart.GetBodyAsText();                           
                    }
                }
            }
        return table;
        }
```

But its fetching emails before 4 March 2016, Not fetching new/latest emails.
Is there any restriction in "OpenPop.Pop3" or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get new emails just put up keyword "recent:" before username then it will give emails which has been received in the last 30 days.

```
 using OpenPop.Pop3;    
    public DataTable ReadEmailsFromId()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
            {
                client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true); //For SSL                
                client.Authenticate("recent:Username", "Password", AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

                int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
                for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    table.Rows.Add(client.GetMessage(i).Headers.Subject, client.GetMessage(i).Headers.DateSent);
                    string msdId = client.GetMessage(i).Headers.MessageId;
                    OpenPop.Mime.Message msg = client.GetMessage(i);
                    OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart plainTextPart = msg.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
                    string message = plainTextPart.GetBodyAsText();                           
                }
            }
        }
    return table;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Gmail over a POP3 has some quirks to it. Try these links and see if they help.

[Get latest mail from the mail server using OpenPop](http://www.nullskull.com/q/10423555/get-latest-mail-from-the-mail-server.aspx)

[What non-standard behaviour features does Gmail exhibit, when it is programmatically used as a POP3 server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530781/what-non-standard-behaviour-features-does-gmail-exhibit-when-it-is-programmatic)